# Slow initialisation of for loop in Python for filter object

Tags: python

I have written some python code to generate a tex file and compile it into a pdf. This works just fine except when I try to rerun the script without changing the name of the compiled pdf while I have a previous version of the pdf opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader.
To solve this, I added the following function before the pdf is compiled to check whether it is still opened in Acrobat and if so, kill Acrobat before compiling the pdf:

```py
def close_file_in_acrobat(file_path):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    all_processes = psutil.process_iter(['name', 'open_files'])
    filtered_processes =  filter(lambda proc: proc.info['name'].lower() == 'acrobat.exe', all_processes)
    for proc in filtered_processes:

        for file in proc.info['open_files']:
            if file_name == os.path.basename(file.path):
                proc.kill()
                return
```

This also works fine but it takes a lot longer than I had expected ~10 seconds.
When looking for which part of the code delays the program, I printed some intermediate values and it turns out the part until `filtered_processes` (including) runs almost instantly and it then takes long to start the first iteration of the `for proc in ...` loop.
I don't see why specifically this part would take so long since the filter object is already generated here.

If there are any suggestions on improving what I'm doing here in general, I'd be more than welcome to hear them as well.

Comment: *the filter object is already generated here* Yes, but `filter` produces a lazy iterator. So `filtered_processes` isn't a list of processes, it's an iterator that yields processes when you consume it. Until you start the `for` loop, nothing from the iterator has been consumed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any applications to be added to TeX it was in 1992 around well before Acrobat (June 15, 1993; 30 years ago) to be written as plain text and at that time DVI screen output.

Time moves on and we now expect PDFTeX to output to a PDF on the screen. So you can type Hello World! on the console and instantly see a PDF without any editor or PDF viewer. (Still do not need Acrobat!).

Thus I start

- `PDFtex story.tex` (C 1992)
  and add my second page by type
- `Hello World!` then
- `\end` and I can console call the editor with
- `texworks story.pdf` and up pops the compiled 2 page Story.PDF.

At this stage I did not add the synctex command that allows inverse calling the text editor but that's just as easy as adding synctex on the console line.

- `pdftex -synctex=1 story.tex`

From that point on I can jump backwards and forwards between the two without either file being locked or blocked.

No Acrobats need to be harmed in using native  PDF LaTeX

[image]

Hence If I add the synctex command I can jump back to source, which is only useful here for going to same letter in the first page as the console entry was not added to the source.tex.

[image]
[image]